# I want to run ipynb file in flask... Please help me to run python files in first page itself so that my model can execute the file then do prediction

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask,request, url_for, redirect, render_template
import pickle
import numpy as np
app = Flask(__name__)

model=pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template("nikit.html")
// I want to run ipynb file so that it can get refreshed and show new output everytime.

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    int_features=[int(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    final=[np.array(int_features)]
    prediction=model.predict(final)
    return render_template('nikit.html',pred = float(prediction*10000) )
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I want to run ipynb file so that it can get refreshed and show new output everytime.
i am working in machine learning model and what I want is my ipynb model to run everytime when I open file web page.

Comment: why you want to run your ipynb notebook file? Wouldn't it be easier to just run your model direclty from that method?

Comment: it is showing previous output, but when I execute ipynb file then run flask app it works well, so I want automate in flask to run ipynb file then show output

Comment: @Kevin is right, but you might be looking for something like [streamlit](https://streamlit.io/)